# Make a table match a specific design

Tags: html

[This is the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQdjc.png)
[I want to design the table like this in HTML and CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZAJzN.png)

I am beginner in HTML.

I  tried making this table but am not getting exact table (especially 
 a line after every row). I just need a code for two rows, the rest I can code on my own.

```css
table#tbl {
 table-layout:fixed;
 word-wrap : break-word;
 text-align:right;
 
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;" id="tbl" >
 <thead>
   <tr>
     <th style="text-align:left" width="3%">Sr no.</th>
     <th style="text-align:left" width="25%" >Item</th>
  <th width="15%">HSN</th>
  <th width="5%">Qty</th>
  <th width="10%">Rate/ Item</th>
  <th width="10%">Discount/ Item</th>
  <th width="10%">Taxable Value</th>
  <th width="8%">SGST</th>
  <th width="8%">CGST</th>
  <th width="12%">Total</th>
   </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align:center"> 1</td>
  <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
  <td> AFG41205</td>
  <td> 10sc.</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 10.00</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 1500.00</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align:center"> 2</td>
  <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
  <td> AFG41205</td>
  <td> 10sc.</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 10.00</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 1500.00</td>
   </tr>
   
   <tr>
     <td style="text-align:center"> 3</td>
  <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
  <td> AFG41205</td>
  <td> 10sc.</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 10.00</td>
  <td> 150.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 20.00</td>
  <td> 1500.00</td>
   </tr>
 <tbody>
 <tfoot>
   <tr>
     <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> Total</td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
   </tr>
  </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Since you are a beginner, I'll mention a few things: 1 - don't use inline styles in your code.  It's difficult to maintain, and makes the code bloated.  2 - use classes in your rows / elements to help control the styling of them. 3 - if you have access to view the original table you're trying to copy, learn to use your developer tools to "inspect" and see how they did it in the original - I've learned a lot doing that (both good and bad!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the `border-bottom` and `border-top` on each `tr` using this:

```
table#tbl tbody tr {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
```

Note that I am not styling the `tr` elements under `thead` - which means that the border will not be created at the top of the table. If you need that, you can replace the selector with: `table#tbl tr`

However you will also need `border-collapse: collapse` on the table for this to work.

Apart from that I've also added a `padding: 10px 0` on the `td` elements in the table. This applies a 10px padding at top and bottom of every cell in the table.

Finally, you can set the background on the `thead` and `tfoot` elements:

```
table#tbl thead,
table#tbl tfoot {
  background-color: #fffdf1;
}
```

Note that your structure of `tbody` element is slightly incorrect in the question. Specifically, you closed the `<tfoot>` tag with `</tbody>` instead of `</tfoot>`. So, I have fixed too, in snippet below.

You can see the snippet below:

```css
table#tbl {
  table-layout: fixed;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  text-align: right;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

table#tbl tbody tr {
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}

table#tbl td {
  padding: 10px 0;
  vertical-align: top;
}

table#tbl thead,
table#tbl tfoot {
  background-color: #fffdf1;
}
```

```html
<table style="width:100%;margin-top:8px;" id="tbl">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th style="text-align:left" width="3%">Sr no.</th>
      <th style="text-align:left" width="25%">Item</th>
      <th width="15%">HSN</th>
      <th width="5%">Qty</th>
      <th width="10%">Rate/ Item</th>
      <th width="10%">Discount/ Item</th>
      <th width="10%">Taxable Value</th>
      <th width="8%">SGST</th>
      <th width="8%">CGST</th>
      <th width="12%">Total</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"> 1</td>
      <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
      <td> AFG41205</td>
      <td> 10sc.</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 10.00</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 1500.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"> 2</td>
      <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
      <td> AFG41205</td>
      <td> 10sc.</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 10.00</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 1500.00</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td style="text-align:center"> 3</td>
      <td style="text-align:left"> Himalaya Herbal Cream<br>Neem Edition </td>
      <td> AFG41205</td>
      <td> 10sc.</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 10.00</td>
      <td> 150.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 20.00</td>
      <td> 1500.00</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> Total</td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
      <td> </td>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
</table>
```

Finally, it looks like that table is using [Open Sans](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Open+Sans) font. I have not applied them in the snippet, but you can follow the instructions in the link to set it up in your application.

Comment: and one more. How do I add space in between two rows

Comment: One of the ways of doing that is through padding. I have already mentioned that in the answer.